# Scrapy: set cookies for a response (no from request)

Tags: python, cookies, scrapy, request, response

I need to extract some wages in USD currency, but I am accessing the page from another country, then, the currency shown is the local (riel) one and no USD. So, I am sending cookies to request a new currency and a new country

In Settings I have:

```
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
COOKIES_DEBUG = True
```

In the Spider I use:

```
class HtSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sells'
    allow_domain = ['hattrick.org']

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://www.hattrick.org']
        for url in urls:
            player = 'goto.ashx?path=/Club/Players/Player.aspx?playerId=450940600'
            joint = urljoin(url, player)
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=joint,
                cookies={'currency': 'USD', 'country': 'US'},
                # meta={'dont_merge_cookies': True},
                dont_filter=True,callback=self.price)
    def price(self,response):
       price_xpath = response.xpath('//* [@id="transferHistory"]/table//tr[1]/td[6]/text()').extract_first()
       print(price_xpath) // it is not in USD but in Riel :(
       open_in_browser(response) // to check if it is in Riel or in USD
```

Then, from the cookies debug I obtain:

```
DEBUG: Sending cookies to: <GET https://www.hattrick.org/en/Club/Players/Player.aspx?playerId=450940600> 
Cookie: currency=USD; country=US; currency=USD; country=US; ASP.NET_SessionId=xxxxx
2021-01-05 16:33:13 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies] DEBUG: Received cookies from: <200 https://www.hattrick.org/en/Club/Players/Player.aspx?playerId=450940600>
Set-Cookie: InitialOrigin=Origin=direct|&DateSet=2021-01-05 10:33:13;
```

`**Print price: 2 280 000 Riel**`

**How to get the cookies I send in the request instead of the ones from the website? In short... how to get USD and not Riels?**

Answer (score 1):

First, have you tested with Postman to make sure that it actually works with this cookie?

If you have `COOKIES_ENABLED = False` then scrapy will not send your cookies to the target server. Since you're only sending the one request to the server the cookies from the server will not be considered. So setting `COOKIES_ENABLED = True` should solve it.

However, if you need to send multiple requests to the server, then this might not work since the `set_cookies` headers from the server might override your cookie.

To solve this I would set `COOKIES_ENABLED = False`.
Then send request like this:

```
yield scrapy.Request(
    url=joint,
    headers={
         'cookies': 'currency:USD;country:US'
    }
    dont_filter=True,callback=self.price)
```

I'm, using headers instead of cookies because if you have disabled cookies in settings, then cookies field would be considered.

Comment: Hi @felix-eklöf, Thank you for your answer. I tried both options for `Cookies_enable` (False and True), and the `Headers` too, but the problem persists. I can send the Cookies, but they don't overwrite the ones from the server. Any other suggestion?

Comment: I toke a closer look at the website, even when I change the language to en-US on the website I still get the wage in my local currency. And I can't find the header you attached anywhere, where did you find it? To me it seems like the server is geotargeting on the server side. Sometimes you can bypass this with Accept-Language header but it didn't work for this server. Only option I can think of is to use a proxy API with US geotargeting.

Comment: Hi Felix. Yes, I checked with Postman and it is geotargeted. I will check with the proxy API as you recommend.